# Android gcm push notifications working perfectly on emulator but not on device?

Tags: android, push-notification, emulation, google-cloud-messaging

GCM server side is working fine. GCM Client side is working fine for emulator but not for device.
GCM SERVICE IS WORKING FINE FOR EMULATOR.

Below is my manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.spidertechnologiesllp.yay"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.spidertechnologiesllp.yay.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.spidertechnologiesllp.yay.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Permission to vibrate -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/yayicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.spidertechnologiesllp.yay.YayTabActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.spidertechnologiesllp.yay" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name=".GCMNotificationIntentService"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.spidertechnologiesllp.yay.YayPredictionActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.spidertechnologiesllp.yay.YayOptionsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.spidertechnologiesllp.yay.YayLoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

STRUGGLING SINCE 2 DAYS.
ANY HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youdint not place permission in com.spidertechnologiesllp.permission is missing

Replace this in manifest file
`<permission
        android:name="com.spidertechnologiesllp.yay.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />`

Comment: it took me hours to find this issue.